# getting only excel file names from ftp java

Tags: java, ftp

I want to get only files having extension .xls from FTP

I made following code:

```
 public  String[] GetFileList()
    {
         String ftpServerIP = Ftp_Path;
         String ftpUserID = Ftp_UserName;
         String ftpPassword = Ftp_Password;

         FTPFile[] downloadFiles = null;

         StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
         FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

         try {
            ftp.connect("ftp://173.201.0.1/");
            ftp.login(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);

            downloadFiles=ftp.listFiles();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return downloadFiles;

    }
```

but its not returning xls files only.

Please help me. how can i achieve it.

I am new with java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the strings returned from the ftp client. Below is an example how to do this.

```
List<String> xlsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String i : downloadFiles) {
    if(i.endsWith(".xls")) {
        xlsFiles.add(i);
    }
}
```

The `xlsFiles` `List` will contain only files ending with `".xls"`.

Edit:

It appears your example won't compile due not using `FTPClient` API correctly. `FTPClient.listFiles()` returns an array of `FTPFiles`.

```
FTPFiles[] downloadFiles = ftp.listFiles();
List<FTPFile> xlsFiles = new ArrayList<FTPFile>();
for(FTPFilei : downloadFiles) {
    if(i.getName().endsWith(".xls")) {
        xlsFiles.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have type of downloadFiles is FTPFile[]

Answer (score 5):

With Java 8 you can use lambda function

```
FTPFileFilter filter=ftpFile -> (ftpFile.isFile() &&  ftpFile.getName().contains(".xls"));
FTPFile[] result = ftpClient.listFiles(dirToSearch, filter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to create your own file filter. ApacheFTP  has this feature.

```
        FTPFileFilter filter = new FTPFileFilter() {                 
            @Override
            public boolean accept(FTPFile ftpFile) {

                return (ftpFile.isFile() && ftpFile.getName().contains(".xls"));
            }
        };

        FTPFile[] result = ftpClient.listFiles(dirToSearch, filter);
```